# I am working on window based report application. I am facing #Error at run time when value will "*"

Tags: reporting-services

```
=IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) Is Nothing AND First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) Is Nothing)
        ,"" , IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) AND First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) Is Nothing)
            ,"" , IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) Is Nothing AND First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value))
                ,"NOT SELECTED", IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="") OrElse (First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = "")
                    , "-" , IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="*") OrElse (First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = "*")
                        ,"*", IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="1" AND First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = "1")
                            ,Code.ChangeWord(First(Fields!CIPDetergentLevel.Value)), "NOT SELECTED"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    =IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) Is Nothing)
        ,"" , IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) Is Nothing)
            ,"NOT SELECTED", IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="") Or First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = "")
                , "-" , IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="*") Or (First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = "*")
                    ,"*", IIf((First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="1" AND First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = "1")
                        ,Code.ChangeWord(First(Fields!CIPDetergentLevel.Value)), "NOT SELECTED"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 expressions which don't return any boolean value

When you want to check a field returns a value use an expression like `Not(Field.Value Is Nothing)` or `FieldValue IsNot Nothing`

Also I would suggest using Switch instead of nested Iif to improve readability

```
=Switch(
    First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) Is Nothing And First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) Is Nothing, "",
    First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) IsNot Nothing And First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) Is Nothing ,"",
    First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) Is Nothing And First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value)  IsNot Nothing ,"NOT SELECTED",
    First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="" Or First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = ""  , "-",
    First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="*" Or First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = "*"  ,"*",
    First(Fields!CIPDetergentRep.Value) ="1" And First(Fields!CIPDetergentSelect.Value) = "1"  ,Code.ChangeWord(First(Fields!CIPDetergentLevel.Value)), 
    True, "NOT SELECTED"
)
```